# Update All Values in MySQL Column to Follow Pattern

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in a table of a MySQL database that stores numbers separated by commas. Here's an example:

```
,,322,,,,455,,,,698,,,,722,
```

There is a specific pattern:

- The first number always has two commas before it
- The numbers in between the first and last are separated by 4 commas
- The last number is followed by a single comma
- The numbers are ALWAYS separated by commas

I'm having some difficulty maintaining this pattern.. sometimes this field updates incorrectly resulting in too many or too few commas in certain places like so:

```
,,166,,,,845,,,,,,,,846,
```

I use this PHP to add/remove commas:

```
public function serializeArray($array) {
    $string = ',';
    foreach ($array as $obj) {
        $string .= ',' . $obj . ',';
    }
return $string;
}

public function unserializeArray($string) {
    $array = explode(",,",$string);
    unset($array[0]);
    $array = array_values($array);

    return $array;

    echo "Array: " . print_r($array);

}
```

SQL to update column:

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare(
    'UPDATE `' . $this->table . '` SET 
        `team_ids` = :team_ids
    WHERE `id` = :customer_id LIMIT 1;');

$query->bindParam(':customer_id', $customer_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':team_ids', $team_ids);
$query->execute();
```

What SQL can I use to UPDATE all of the values in the column to follow the specific pattern requirements mentioned above?

Comment: what sql have you tried already?

Comment: Why don't you normalise the data rather then storing csv data in each row? In the long run it'll be more maintainable.

Comment: I have to agree with AeroX, normalize the data if you can.

Comment: Thanks Ill do that next :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here looks like you're missing a number, not that it is not following your pattern.

```
,,166,,,,845,,,,Missing No,,,,846,
```

Are you sure you want to delete this?  I would instead focus on catching the null or blank number.

If so, it looks like you should be able to do a replace

```
Update   TableName
Set      NumberPattern = Replace(NumberPattern, ',,,,,,,,', ',,,,') --Repalce 8 ',' with 4 ','
```

Comment: You are correct in that the extra commas are a result of missing numbers, however, the string doesn't always look exactly like that. Sometimes it looks like: ,,141,,,,879,,,,848,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, Sometimes it looks like: ,,,,,,394,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Assuming it is just because of a missing number you could just rerun the script until it affects 0 rows. If you truly wanna optimize add on a " Where contains 8,"

Comment: This should be a fix not a permanent solution, as mentioned you should either normalize data or properly handle missing numbers.